# Typings for recursive function

Tags: typescript, recursion, monads

I'm trying to write a `unwrap` method of a class that holds a value, or an instance of itself with an inner value:

```js
class Identity<T> {
  private readonly value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  static of<T>(value: T): Identity<T> {
    return new Identity(value);
  }

  join(): T { // which return type should go here?
    if (this.value instanceof Identity) {
      return this.value.join();
    }

    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Here is the test:

```js
const one = Identity.of(Identity.of(Identity.of(123)));
const result: number = one.join();
expect(result).toEqual(123);
```

Thanks you folks!!

Comment: You could remove one "level" of `Identity` by unwrapping using `infer`, but doing so recursively AFAIK is not possible, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your type parameter `T`, so that it always is the fully nested type:

```js
class Identity<T> {
  private readonly value: T | Identity<T>;

  constructor(value: Identity<T>);
  constructor(value: T);

  constructor(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  static of<T>(value: Identity<T>): Identity<T>;
  static of<T>(valud: T): Identity<T>;
  static of<T>(value: T | Identity<T>) {
    return new Identity(value);
  }

  join(): T {
    if (this.value instanceof Identity) {
      return this.value.join();
    }
    return this.value;
  }
}

const one = Identity.of(Identity.of(Identity.of(123)));
const result: number = one.join();

const result2 = new Identity(new Identity(new Identity(321)));
// Identity<number>
```

I would suggest the above method, as it seems to provide the functionality you actually want.

If you need the type `T` to actually be a nested `Identity<Identity<...>>` it is still possible, if `value` was public we could do the following:

```js
class Identity<T> {
  public readonly value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  static of<T>(value: T): Identity<T> {
    return new Identity(value);
  }

  public join(): IdentityJoinResult<T> {
    if (this.value instanceof Identity) {
      return this.value.join();
    }

    return this.value as IdentityJoinResult<T>;
  }
}

type IdentityJoinResult<T> = 
  T extends Identity<any>
    ? { [Key in keyof T]: IdentityJoinResult<T[Key]> }["value"]
    : T
;

const one = Identity.of(Identity.of(Identity.of(123)));
const result: number = one.join();

const result2 = new Identity(new Identity(new Identity(321))).join();
```

However if you change `value` to be private you will notice that you are no longer able to index by "value" in the type signature, so the last thing we can do to fix this is to defer our type logic to a separate public interface which we can determine from the type:

```js
class Identity<T> {
  private readonly value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  static of<T>(value: T): Identity<T> {
    return new Identity(value);
  }

  public join(): IdentityJoinResult<T> {
    if (this.value instanceof Identity) {
      return this.value.join();
    }

    return this.value as IdentityJoinResult<T>;
  }
}

interface NestedIdentity<T> {
  _value: T extends Identity<infer U> ? NestedIdentity<U> : T;
}

type NestedIdentityValue<T> = 
  T extends NestedIdentity<any>
    ? { [Key in keyof T]: NestedIdentityValue<T[Key]> }["_value"]
    : T
;

type IdentityJoinResult<T> = NestedIdentityValue<NestedIdentity<T>>;

const one = Identity.of(Identity.of(Identity.of(123)));
const result: number = one.join();
const result2 = new Identity(new Identity(new Identity(321))).join();
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. The type of `one` here is just `Identity<number>`, it should be (as far as I know), `Identity<Identity<Identity<number>>>`.

Comment: This answer is working indeed, but not sure why... And I'm not confident enough with TypeScript to tell if it's well done. :/

Comment: @DanielRamos If you only need the functionality you indicated in your question, I would suggest going with the first method I posted, it basically just makes the type information not know or care about how deep the identity chain is. I've updated my answer if you need the types to reflect the actual length of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

As Ingo mentioned in comments, `infer` would work if it weren't for a limitation in TS.

```
class Identity<T> {
  private readonly value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  static of<T>(value: T): Identity<T> {
    return new Identity(value);
  }

  join(): T extends Identity<infer U> ? U : T {
    if (this.value instanceof Identity) {
      return this.value.join() ;
    }

    return this.value as any;

    // return this.value as T;
  }
}

const one = Identity.of(Identity.of(Identity.of(123)));
const result = one.join();
expect(result).toEqual(123);
```

```
T extends Identity<infer U> ? U : T
```

is the key, here.

Comment: Hey Tyler thanks you your response. Yes, it removes one level of nesting, but the three of them as you are posting in the example still results in a  `Identity<number>` :(